# SUMMARIZE or SUM values based on Date fields in another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, burndowncharts

I am trying to do a burndown graph on PowerBI.

My data is a list of tasks. Each task has a numerical value (EFFORT) assigned to it and there is a total amount of effort for any given month (sum of all EFFORT). As tasks as set to DONE, the ongoing effort should be deducted from a running total and that value used to plot a graph. I have 3 columns

[image]

I would like to have measure to calculate EFFORT REMAINING for each date, i.e.

```
EFFORT REMAINING = TOTAL EFFORT - (EFFORT WHEN TASKS ARE DONE FOR EACH DAY)
```

For example,

[image]

I did get the consecutive dates displaying:

```
Burndown = CALENDAR(DATE(2022,7,1),DATE(2022,7,31))
```

[image]

and also the total effort (starting value)

```
TOTAL EFFORT = SUM(Issues[EFFORT])
```

Now for each date in table, I need to minus the accumulating total of EFFORT when the status is set to DONE

```
EFFORT REMAINING = Burndown[TOTAL EFFORT]-SUM(Issues[EFFORT]="DONE" ....
```

Im stuck after this last point. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are so close to the answer ). Convert `SUM(Issues[EFFORT]="DONE"` to:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Issues[EFFORT])
    , SUM(Issues[Status]="DONE"
)
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this measure:

Please ensure that (1-Many) relationship is created between Burndown [Date] and Issues[ISSUE_CREATED] columns.

```
EFFORT REMAINING =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Issues, Burndown[Date] ),
        "Total Effort", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ) ),
        "Tasks Completed", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ), Issues[STATUS] = "DONE" ),
        "Effort Remaining",
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ) )
                - CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ), Issues[STATUS] = "DONE" )
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [Effort Remaining] )
RETURN
    Result
```

After that, you can create a clustered column chart, and put [Date field] on calendar table on X_axis and put 'EFFORT REMAINING' measure on Y_axis(Value axis) to see the result.

I hope It solves your problem.

Bonus Info:
If you want to see your Summary table, create a "New Table" and paste this code:

```
Summary_Table =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Issues, Burndown[Date] ),
        "Total Effort", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ) ),
        "Tasks Completed", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ), Issues[STATUS] = "DONE" ),
        "Effort Remaining",
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ) )
                - CALCULATE ( SUM ( Issues[EFFORT] ), Issues[STATUS] = "DONE" )
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [Effort Remaining] )
RETURN
    TblSummary
```

The result It produces:
Note: I have limited access to your data sets as you shared above. The result will be exact with your full dataset.

[image: KJK]